# Understanding startup circuit in this power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback

This design is from  a TI App Note: http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10195

I want to understand the behavior of the circuit around Q3 and Q4. As far as I understand Q3 is turned on first for the VIN and and ULVO pins. Then when U1 is turned ON it activates Q4 and consequently turns Q3 off?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, Q3 is in the on-state first as it, in combination with D20, is part of a simple linear regulator.  The output of which will be roughly around 24V minus the threshold voltage of Q3.

Q4 is driven by the output of the PWM regulator, U20, through a low pass filter formed by R100 and C19, which is tuned for the switching frequency of U20, 32kHz, and expected PWM duty cycle and keeps the gate voltage on Q4 high enough to keep Q4 on as long as U20 is generating the PWM output.